# Как правильно распарсить дату?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

***Код:***

```java
dper.setV_date(request.getOperationDate() != null ? new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("02.07.2018"):null);
```

***Ошибка:***

```java
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02.07.2018"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.is.korona_pay.KoronaPayDBHelper.insertHandleOperation(KoronaPayDBHelper.java:292)
```

Comment: Это Я нечайно опечатку поставил, за ранее Извиняюсь.

Comment: Это от того, что в шаблоне есть время, а в строке нет. Было бы `parse("02.07.2018 00:00:00")` все было бы нормально. В java 8 можно воспользоваться классом `DateTimeFormatter`, который позволяет указать шаблон с необязательными частями

Comment: Я работаю на 6 ЯВЕ, 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02.07.2018 00:00:00"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.is.korona_pay.KoronaPayDBHelper.insertHandleOperation(KoronaPayDBHelper.java:293)

Comment: Можно выполнить какую-то элементарную проверку входной строки (например длина > 10) и выбрать один из шаблонов: либо полный `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`, либо только с датой `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main { 

    private final static String INPUT_PATERN = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    private final static String OUTPUT_PATERN = "dd.MM.yyyy";

    private final static String DATE_TEXT = "Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 UZT 2018";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        //befor java 8
        DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(INPUT_PATERN, Locale.US);
        Date date = inputFormatter.parse(DATE_TEXT);        
        DateFormat outputFormatter =new SimpleDateFormat(OUTPUT_PATERN);
        outputFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PLT"));
        System.out.println(outputFormatter.format(date));  

        //java 8
        DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(INPUT_PATERN).withLocale(Locale.US);
        ZonedDateTime localeDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(DATE_TEXT, formater);
        System.out.println(localeDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(OUTPUT_PATERN)));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы задаете формат даты с временем, а по факту у вас времени нету во входных данных
Вот так всё будет работать:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("02.07.2018");
```

Comment: Ситуация изначально такая ко мне приходит вот такая дата  "Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 UZT 2018" c таким форматом "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", а мне нужно ее распарсить в такой формат "dd.MM.yyyy" 
Cейчас Я пытаюсь сделать так
dper.setV_date(request.getOperationDate() != null ? new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse("02.07.2018 00:00:00"):null);

Comment: То, что у вас написано в аргументе метода `parse` должно попадать под шаблон, указанный в конструкторе `SimpleDateFormat`. У вас это не так.

Comment: @JohnWilliams, вам дата приходит в строке или в объекте `Date`? Если в строке, её нужно распарсить, если в объекте Date, то её можно так и хранить, а форматирование делать только при выводе куда-либо. Не слишком понятен вопрос теперь.